# How to deal with massive retagging on a meta website?

Tags: discussion, tags, per-site-meta

I was looking through [meta.codereview.SE](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/) and was flagging the questions on which I thought the site-policy tag was relevant as it can lead to clearer site-policy in the long run. I flagged 9 questions and then thought that this was getting really silly.

How can I deal with such massive retagging on a meta website when I don't have edit previliges? Is there a better way than flagging each question?

Comment: [With the right tools, the job can be much easier.](http://stackapps.com/questions/4207/burninator-toolkit)  I've got an alternate script that switches tags automatically.  Haven't dropped it on stackapps yet, so let me know if replacing tag A with tag B would be helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try compiling a list of all the questions you think should have the tag, and create a meta-Meta question about adding the tag to all those questions. If the community agrees, they will help you out in the retagging. Flagging them all in bulk for moderator attention is not a very efficient way of doing it, and will only add unnecessary work for the moderators.

Comment: Meta, meta-meta, meta-meta-flagging, how deep does it go?!?!

Comment: I realized that it isn't efficient way of doing it. That's why I asked this question. I'll do that.